# Angular2 RouterLink in child component is expecting route to be defined in parent component

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I am using two components one is parent component and the second one is child component in its template. Now in child component I have defined a route and placed a router outlet and a router link in child component's template. So that when I click on this link it should update the contents at its own router outlet but its giving the following error and is searching for a route to be defined in its parent component:

```
EXCEPTION: Component "ParentComponent" has no route config.in[['ChildRoute'] in ChildComponent@2: 26]
```

The components are:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-cmp',
    template: '<child-cmp></child-cmp>',
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        ChildComponent
    ]
})
export class ParentComponent { }

@Component({
    selector: 'child-cmp',
    template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <a [routerLink]="['ChildRoute']">Edit</a>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/edit', name: 'ChildRoute', component: ChildEditComponent }
])
export class ChildComponent { }
```

Assuming the imports are correct, I haven't mentioned here for brevity.

Answer (score 4):

When you make the link to child route defines the route father before

try this,

```
<a [routerLink]="['ParentRoute','ChildRoute']">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Great. This worked when I was trying to link to a component in ChildRoute from ParentRoute's component.

Answer (score 1):

To access child route from parent, always use

```
<a [routerLink]=['ParentRouteElement','ChildRouteElement']
```

and should have one childrouteElement asDefault also.

Answer (score 0):

In main Route config you should have:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { name: "Videos", component: ChildrenCmp, path: "/videos/..."}
])
```

Than in child Component:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { name: "ChildCmp" component: ChildCmp, path: "/",
useAsDefault: true}])
```

[Working example on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3dnBZEDhpGvVO5aQQswA?p=preview)

Comment: I have placed my routerLink in child component's template not in parent's, and wants to updated the response in child's routerOutlet

Comment: You must define one - top component as main with router config.

Comment: In that case it is updating the contents of router-outlet of top level component, but I want to updated response in the router-outlet of child component, parent's outlet is simply replacing the child component which I don't want to

Answer (score 0):

When you bootstrap your application, you may have referenced the `ParentComponent` as your router primary component instead of the `ChildComponent`.

You may need to have something like:

```
bootstrap(ParentComponent, [
  // ...
  provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: ChildComponent})
]);
```

Comment: Yes, I have already referenced the parent component while bootstrapping. It's working fine except the routerLink in child component template.

Comment: you provided the ChildComponent or the ParentComponent to ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT ?

Comment: You should try to provide ChildComponent, see my answer

Comment: My bootstrap file: bootstrap(ParentComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);

Comment: As I explained in my answer try with: bootstrap(ParentComponent, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: ChildComponent})]);

Comment: Its a compile time error, I think ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT is no longer supported.

Comment: It is still supported, but you have to import it from 'angular2/router'. If that does not work, give us the compile error

Comment: @AliShahzad did you try?